# Comparing php framework - by their unique features

Tags: php, frameworks

I saw many many compares with php frameworks, but they are just rather general - OOP supported, MVC supported... there are really unique features which distinguish them. `Symfony` has flash variables, `Zend` has tons of classes for general purposes.

Anybody knows such compairing stuff?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP ?

Comment: Comprehensive and up-to-date list: http://alternativeto.net/software/codeigniter/ but overall, I do agree that such a feature comparison would be good to have.

Answer (score 4):

Pick one you hear about, try it, and see what fits. Personally I've fallen for CodeIgniter, and just haven't looked into anything else as I haven't run into a limitation for my purposes.

Its really about picking the best tool for the job.

Comment: +1 because choosing the right tool is the real skill of a good web developer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say look into that table on Wikipedia that *danp* posted. I'd suggest doing some cursory research just by visiting the Wikipedia entries for a few of the top frameworks and pick one. The goal of a framework is to help the programmer to be more productive. If you have a good grasp of PHP and web programming in general, any of the frameworks will be a help.

If you are coming from a Rails background, I would suggest CakePHP or Lithium, since they share a tone of similarities with Rails. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with comparing unique features is that the unique features are mostly stuff you don't care about, otherwise it would already be implemented in the framework. I'd recommend you to go to forums, both people criticising it and raise it to the skies, see what their cases are and why their framework is a fit for them.

Don't just look for what a framework does, but what it does **right**.