# Compare frameworks: spring mvc, struts2, zend, laravel

Tags: laravel, spring-mvc, zend-framework

I must complete the comperation table below. I've searched and filled a few but i'm not sure about my answers. 
Can you help me check them? 
Thanks so much.
[comperation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fke6.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing php framework - by their unique features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835701/comparing-php-framework-by-their-unique-features)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Laravel from the last 5 years, so I can give my perspective on that. According to me, Laravel is easy to learn and fast to develop a framework.

They have artisan commands to create your basic structure very fast. 
Routing - Laravel has now categorized routes according to their area, like web routes, API routes and console routes. so you can easily differentiate your routes according to their use.

**Database** - As you said Eloquent, it is enough powerful. you can use the DB facade as well.

HTML JSON & Image Rendering - Laravel uses a blade template engine so their helpers come very handy. e.g. @yield or @include, now they have even @slots.
helpers are available for assets.

**Login** - just enter one command basic login structure is ready for you. from registration to forgot password. make::auth command is there. it even creates basic database tables for you. you can override it as well. [Authentication Quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart)

**ACL** - You are free to write your own middlewares.[Middleware laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)